# Electron - Need unit testing framework for bundled app

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, electron, electron-builder, testcase

we are using electron framework to create **WINDOWS** and **MAC** installer. For frontend, we are using Angular to show data.
We are also using **sqlite3** database to store data locally in user's system using node.js.

Everything working fine like api calling using **AXIOS**, intercating with our local database(CRUD), intercating with client side(frontend) with **electron-ipc-renderer**, file system handling.
Our application is working properly as expected.

We are stuck with unit testing of our application.

We want to do end to end testing which will consume electrons basic libraries like:-

- **app**
- **BrowserWindow**
- **dialog**
- **Menu**
- **remote**
- **screen**
- **ipcMain**

And we are using other node libraries also like **axios, path, chokidar, sqlite3**.

Has anyone achieved Unit test cases for such kind Electron App/knows anything which can help us?